# gitlab API - how can I create a branch from an issue

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-api

In git lab, you can create an issue, then within the issue you can create a branch.  This branch is linked to the issue (I think because of the issue number at the start of the branch name), such that when you do a merge request on that branch it automatically closes the issue.

So my question is - how can you do this via the API? I can create the issue, but there is no control (as far as I can see) within the issue API to create the related branch.

Is that possible?

It would be nice to be able to create an issue with branch in one go - but I don't think that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - its not perhaps the best answer, but here is what I came up with for a interim solution (in linux bash):

1. Raise the issue store response in `cmd_resp`
2. Extract the issue ID: `echo $cmd_resp | grep -o -P '(?<=iid":).*(?=,"project_id)'`.
   Where the issue ID is found by looking for: `iid":<ISSUE-ID>,"project_id`
3. Create a branch with the name: `<ISSUE-ID>-some-branch-name` - by having the issue ID at the start of the branch name, gitlab automatically makes a relation to that issue.

So - its quite a simple approach, but it does not feel very integrated. I would still prefer to do that from the point of view of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a branch related to an issue via the issues API.

However, this is in line with how RESTful APIs should be designed. If you want to create a branch, you need to make a POST request to the branches API.

```
POST /projects/:id/repository/branches
```

As you have already found out, GitLab is quite good at automatically linking issues, MRs and branches together.
For a branch to be linked to an issue, simply start the branch with the issue ID. However, usually it is enough if a merge request is linked to an issue. In my opinion, you shouldn't really be concerned with the branch. You can later access the branch via issue->MR->branch

Merge requests are linked to issues whenever a MR's description text links to an issue (e.g. #1). If you add an issue ID to the *Closes* statement, the issue will also be closed upon MR resolution.

Therefore, you could simply create a branch via the API, name it however you want. Then, create a MR from that issue and include `Closes #1` in your MR description, where 1 is your issue ID.

Further, I would recommend using a more sophisticated REST client. You shouldn't have to parse the issue ID yourself. It is properly set as a field in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for the method/approach via MR - that sounds good +1 for that (and the answer that I can't do it from issues).  But I specifically only want to raise an issue with the branch linked. The reason is for a special case - otherwise my gitlab IDE does all the work for me already. My use-case is that I have a whole pile of projects that all communicate with each other and so I am having to create issue-branch pairs on them and it gets tedious doing it one by one. So I wrote a script to do it via the gitlab API, it saves me a lot of time!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad you found ways to make it work for you!